# What is the purpose of the import statement in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, inheritance, import

Could someone explain to me what the pupose of the import statement is, in Solidity? Is it the similar to inheriting from another contract where you have access to the state variables and function of that contract?

Answer (score 2):

`import` allows you to practically include the specified file content in the current file, acting as if all the code is in the same page. It's often used for inheritance or to have access to interfaces while keeping a clean file.

Exemple:

Imagine you have two files ContractA.sol and ContractB.sol and you want `ContractB` to use some of the content of ContractA.sol.

ContractA.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

struct Point {
    uint x;
    uint y;
}

contract ContractA {
   address variable1;
   ...

   function function1() ...

}
```

ContractB.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract ContractB {

}
```

In order for `ContractB` to inherit `ContractA`, or for `ContractB` to use the `Point` structure, you can either copy and paste the content of file ContractA.sol in ContractB.sol, or (the easiest and cleaner way) just import ContractA.sol using the `import` statement `import "PATH/ContractA.sol"`. It will then be the same as having the content of both files into one.

With an `import` statement ContractB.sol would look like this for exemple:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;
import "PATH/ContractA.sol"

contract ContractB is ContractA {
   Point someVariable;

   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you made it very clear to understand.